# Element within an Element in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to mandate atleast one choice under "Account" element? (or) 
Is it possible to default one choice under "Account" element?

```
<xs:element name="Account">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:choice>
     <xs:element name="User" type="tns:users"/>
     <xs:element name="Group" type="tns:groups"/>
   </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "mandate at least one choice" you mean require that at least one of User or Group appear, then yes, you can, and the XSD fragment you show does this.  If you mean require that User (for example) occur at least once under each Account, then again yes you can, but in that case the fragment you show doesn't do it.

If by "default one choice" you mean cause a User (for example) to be assumed if the document instance contains neither User nor Group, then no, no XML schema language I know of has that capability (but of course the behavior of your processing software is constrained only by your own ingenuity).  On the other hand, if by "default one choice" you mean supply a default value for Group if the XML document instance contains an empty Group element, then yes, that's possible if Group has a simple type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the first part of the question correctly, the elment `Account` must have a sub-element `User` or a sub-element `Group` or both - but it cannot have no sub-elements, nor multiple `User` or `Group` sub-elements.

If this is the requirement then use:

```
<xs:element name="Account">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="User" type="tns:users"/>
        <xs:element name="Group" type="tns:groups" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Group" type="tns:groups"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I am not sure what you mean by 'default one choice' in the second part of the question.